# Rose "to a crescendo" or "in a crescendo"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, prepositions

What is the correct way of saying that the song grew louder gradually?

1. His song rose in a crescendo
2. His song rose to a crescendo.

Comment: "Rose to a crescendo" is not correct since it's not a destination but a process of getting louder.  It's completely appropriate to say, alternatively though, "His song crescendoed to a glorious fortissimo at its climax."

Comment: @KristinaLopez lovely example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because a song can rise both in pitch and in volume, for clarity you might consider simply using crescendo as a verb:

His song crescendoed.

As for the two options you presented, I would choose "in a crescendo" because the crescendo represents the change in volume, not just the final level. As @mikeagg pointed out, the song may have risen to a climax.

Answer (score 7):

If the song gradually grew louder then it rose *in a crescendo*. It possibly rose to a climax.

Answer (score 6):

To a musician, *crescendo* is an instruction to get louder, and *a crescendo* is the action of getting louder. In this context, *rose to a crescendo* is nonsense.

However, like many technical terms, *crescendo* has been adopted into common language, with a different meaning; in this case, something like *climax*; so *rose to a crescendo* is a common expression.

*Rose in a crescendo* is a possible phrase, preserving the musical meaning, but it is not very likely, because the musical *crescendo* already conveys the sense of increase. I don't think it would be said with the general meaning of *crescendo*.

Comment: I agree, both as to the literal paradox and to the change in meaning due to the crossover to common language. The problem with "rose [in or to] a crescendo" is exactly the same as the problem of "fell [in or to] a diminuendo": The Italian instruction is inherent in the simple English verb, so you'd do better to modify the verb with something like "gradually [or quickly] rose." The phrase "reached a crescendo" has a similar problem, although that might be taken to refer to the specific place in a piece of sheet music where the instruction "Crescendo" ("Begin to increase volume") appears.